# how to set z-index for search/find popup in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

how to set z-index for Find/Replace popup in CKEditor ?
actually i have a ckeditor instance on one popup which is overlapping with the Find/Replace popup. ie Find/Replace popup goes behind my own popup on which i have ckeditor instance

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your ckEditor config.js file `config.baseFloatZIndex = 100001`